# AES key storing

Tags: java, exception, cryptography, aes, keystore

Hi guys I'm having problem storing my AES key into keyStore.

This is my code:

```
public Key getKey(String alias) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        keyStore.load(fStream, this.password.toCharArray());
        Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
        fStream.close();

        return key;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public void storeKey(Key key, String alias) {
    try {
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, key.getEncoded(), null);
        OutputStream writeStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        keyStore.store(writeStream, this.password.toCharArray());
        writeStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So storeKey works fine, but then when I call getKey() i get this exception:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: AES SecretKeyFactory not available
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(Unknown Source)
at sm130075.vl130298.crypto.KeyStoreManager.getKey(KeyStoreManager.java:51)
at sm130075.vl130298.crypto.AES.<init>(AES.java:36)
at sm130075.vl130298.crypto.AES.main(AES.java:84)
```

EDIT:
So I found out that problem is most likely that SecretFactory doesn't know to generate key for AES. Anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add information about your runtime, mainly your brand & version of Java?

Comment: I dont know what do you mean by brand, sorry.
Version is 8 update 77

Comment: FWIW: fixed several months later in 8u102 and 8u111, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8149411